# Revert Approve-Always consent in OIDC

Tags: openid-connect

I am following the specification [1] and once my client app sends the authorization request to my server, first the server asks for authorization then for consent. There are three consents like approve , approve always and deny. When we give approve always the server wont ask for consent again if the client app tries to authorize (without providing prompt=consent) any time even in a different session. My concern is can we revert this 'approve - always' consent?

Once the client sends the authorization request with prompt=consent then the server will asks for consent even we have a pre-configured consent. At this point when the client sends prompt=consent with the authorization request can we revert the pre-configured consent? Any feedback is highly appreciated.

[1] :http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an implementation decision: the OpenID Connect provider could decide to interpret the `prompt=consent` as overriding the previously stored decision and display a consent screen again. In fact the spec says that the Provider `SHOULD` do so. But since it is not a must, the Provider may decide to implement things differently and you'll have to look into the software implementation to change that.